# Mocha unit test for Promise throws error

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

I'm trying to unit test a promise. Here is the code :

```
it('it should return some 10 user data with ok status code when called with url ', (done) => {
    return user.getUsers('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .then((response) => {
        console.log('me here')
        assert.equal(JSON.parse(response).length, 10)
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
        console.log('me in error')
        assert.fail('err')
    })
})
```

The above code when run throws the following error :

`Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (C:\Users\ajay\jay-workspace\UniTestModule\test\user.test.js)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`done` isn't called, this results in test timeout.

Mocha natively supports promises. `done` shouldn't be used when there are promises; instead, promises should be returned:

```
it('it should return some 10 user data with ok status code when called with url ', () => {
    return user.getUsers('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .then((response) => {
        console.log('me here')
        assert.equal(JSON.parse(response).length, 10)
    });
})
```

Rejected promise will fail the test, no need for `assert.fail` as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should call done() callback when using async testing (for details check https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code).

```
it('it should return some 10 user data with ok status code when called with url ', (done) => {
user.getUsers('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
.then((response) => {
    console.log('me here')
    assert.equal(JSON.parse(response).length, 10);
    done();
})
.catch((err)=>{
    console.log('me in error')
    assert.fail('err');
    done(err);
})
```

Comment: ```Error: Resolution method is overspecified. Specify a callback *or* return a Promise; not both.```

Comment: It seems you need to remove "return" statement from your test.

Comment: @Ilia You need to do the opposite, remove `done`. There's already a promise, using `done` results in verbose and less reliable code. Regarding 'less reliable', this is exactly the case. The code you've posted won't work. `assert.fail` throws an error. `done()` (btw, it should be `done(err)`, otherwise the test passes) is never reached. This results in test timeout and uncaught rejection

Answer (score 0):

You should use `--timeout` hook and increase the number of ms like `./node_module/.bin/mocha test/ --timeout=5000` 
OR you can add `this.timeout(5000)` in the test case body

```
it('it should return some 10 user data with ok status code when called with url ', (done) => {
user.getUsers('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
.then((response) => {
    console.log('me here')
    assert.equal(JSON.parse(response).length, 10);
    this.timeout(5000);
    setTimeout(done, 3000);
})
```

https://mochajs.org/#test-level